# When trying to reference a DLL project in the same solution as my EXE project, I get an error "Cannot open include file: 'iostream'

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to create a game and then link to my engine DLL library which references static libraries such as Math, Utils, Entities, Physics, etc. I'm new to DLLs and I've only ever   linked to them, and never actually built them (same with static libs). I'm trying to link my console app to my engine DLL, but when I include a header file in my console app from my engine I get an error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this?

Also, is this a good use of DLL files and static libraries? I'm trying to organize my code more professionally, even in a small project like this.

Edit: I forgot to mention the header file I'm including from engine into console app includes the iostream file, if that wasn't obvious before to you.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add how you are including the `iostream` file?

Comment: Just `#include <iostream>` at the top of the header file in the DLL.

Comment: Are the include directories for the console app project set similarly to the include directories of the DLL project?  It seems like the include directory containing `iostream` is not on the console app's include directory list...

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if you have included the required header files in your project.

```
#include<iostream>
```

Comment: In the console application I need to include the files too? But yes I have included iostream in the engine dll.